# Unable to unwrap a large Int

Tags: swift

I have a `Dictionary` object containing a large number (epoch time). When I try to cast it as an `Int` the result is an entirely different number. Trying to explicitly cast it as an `Int64` or `String` both yield `nil`.

```
(lldb) po postData["createdDate"]
▿ Optional<AnyObject>
  ▿ Some : 1 elements
    - [0] : 1461681488000

(lldb) po postData["createdDate"] as? [Int]
▿ Optional<Array<Int>>
  ▿ Some : 1 elements
    - [0] : 1392607360

(lldb) po postData["createdDate"] as? [Int64]
nil

(lldb) po postData["createdDate"] as? [String]
nil
```

I'm on a 64 bit system and am well below the ceiling for an `Int64`. What's going on here, and how do I access this number?

*PS: I'm aware dates should be transmitted in ISO 8601 format but this is the input I'm dealing with.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numeric dictionary objects are bridged to `NSNumber`.

Cast the value to `NSNumber` and get the `longLongValue`

```
if let epochTime = postData["createdDate"] as? NSNumber {
  let longNumber : Int64 = epochTime.longLongValue
}
```